# Empty response in Spotify Web API Auth with Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I got stuck in the Auth section while using Spotify Web API. I am using Hilt and Retrofit.
When I send a request, respond returns empty. But returns code 200. That's why i can't get tokens. Secondly, auth and api base url's are different. How to handle this situation?

(auth: https://accounts.spotify.com/api/, api: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/)

**Response in App Inspector:**
[image: Response in App Inspector]

**My ApiModule**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(builder: Retrofit.Builder): SpotifyApi {
        return builder
            .build()
            .create(SpotifyApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit.Builder {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        networkStatusInterceptor: NetworkStatusInterceptor,
        authenticationInterceptor: AuthenticationInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(networkStatusInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(authenticationInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .build()
    }
}
```

**My AuthenticationInterceptor**

```
class AuthenticationInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    private val preferences: Preferences
) : Interceptor {

    companion object {
        const val UNAUTHORIZED = 401
    }

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val token = preferences.getToken()
        val tokenExpirationTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(preferences.getTokenExpirationTime())
        val request = chain.request()

        val interceptedRequest: Request

        if (tokenExpirationTime.isAfter(Instant.now())) {
            interceptedRequest = chain.createAuthenticatedRequest(token)
        } else {

            val tokenRefreshResponse = chain.refreshToken()

            interceptedRequest = if (tokenRefreshResponse.isSuccessful) {
                val newToken = mapToken(tokenRefreshResponse)
                if (newToken.isValid()) {
                    storeNewToken(newToken)
                    chain.createAuthenticatedRequest(newToken.accessToken!!)
                } else {
                    request
                }
            } else {
                request
            }
        }
        return chain.proceedDeletingTokenIfUnauthorized(interceptedRequest)
    }

    private fun Interceptor.Chain.createAuthenticatedRequest(token: String): Request {
        return request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader(AUTH_HEADER, TOKEN_TYPE + token)
            .build()
    }

    private fun Interceptor.Chain.refreshToken(): Response {

        val requestBody = FormBody.Builder()
            .add(GRANT_TYPE_KEY, GRANT_TYPE_VALUE)
            .add(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_ID_VALUE)
            .add(CLIENT_SECRET, CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE)
            .build()

        val request = request()
            .newBuilder()
            .url("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()

        return proceedDeletingTokenIfUnauthorized(request)
    }

    private fun Interceptor.Chain.proceedDeletingTokenIfUnauthorized(request: Request): Response {
        val response = proceed(request)

        if (response.code == UNAUTHORIZED) {
            preferences.deleteTokenInfo()
        }

        return response
    }

    private fun mapToken(tokenRefreshResponse: Response): ApiToken {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val tokenAdapter = moshi.adapter(ApiToken::class.java)
        val responseBody = tokenRefreshResponse.body!!

        return tokenAdapter.fromJson(responseBody.toString()) ?: ApiToken.INVALID
    }

    private fun storeNewToken(apiToken: ApiToken) {
        with(preferences) {
            putTokenType(apiToken.tokenType!!)
            putTokenExpirationTime(apiToken.expiresAt)
            putToken(apiToken.accessToken!!)
        }
    }
}
```

**My api interface**

```
interface SpotifyApi {
    @GET(ApiConstants.PLAYLIST_ENDPOINT + "{playlistId}")
    suspend fun getPlaylist(
        @Path("playlistId") playlistId: String
    ): ApiPlaylist
}
```

Comment: What happens when you make the request outside of the application? I.E. using Postman. What do you see there?

Comment: Everything works. Response is have data.

Comment: Are you sure that the headers and request parameters are the same?